# Recursive function on sorted array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to solve this problem recursively:  `Clean the room function: given an input of [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20], make a function that organizes these into individual array that is ordered. For example answer(ArrayFromAbove) should return: [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,[20,20], 391, 392,591]`

```
Array:
const array1 = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];
array1.sort((a,b) => a-b);
```

Main Function:

```
const sortArray = (mainArr) => {
    let acc = [];
    console.log(acc, "acc");
    const recursive = (arr) => {

        if (arr.length > 1) {
            console.log("inside func2 ", acc);
            let likeArr = singArr(arr, arr[0]);
            console.log(likeArr, "like");
            arr = deleteVal(arr, arr[0]);
            acc.push(likeArr);
            return recursive(mainArr);
        }
        else {
            return acc;
        }
    }
};
```

Helper Functions:

```
const singArr = (arr1, val) => { 
    let returnVal = arr1.filter(num => num === val);
    return (returnVal.length === 1 ? returnVal[0] : returnVal);
};

const deleteVal = (arr, val) => {
    let returnVal = arr.filter(num => num !== val);
    return returnVal
};
```

Idea is to go through the array that I've sorted, filter using the first item in the array to get back a new array (single value if there's only one) with the like items, push it to my accumulator and then delete every instance of it in the original array.

I'm trying to do this recursively until there are no items left in the original array but it's returning undefined.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: just for fun: `Object.values(array1.reduce((o,v)=>({...o,[v]:v in o?[].concat(o[v],v):v}),{}))` or `array1.sort((a,b)=>a-b).reduce((acc,v,i,a)=>(a[i-1]===v?acc[acc.length-1].push(v):acc.push(a[i+1]===v?[v]:v)) && acc,[])`

Comment: Like a couple of people said before had to call ```recursive(mainArray)``` outside of the recursive function. Then inside 'recursive' call it with arr instead of mainArray since arr was the one being updated. ```return recursive(arr)```;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the `recursive` function from outside of the function.

```
const sortArray = (mainArr) => {
    let acc = [];
    console.log(acc, "acc");
    const recursive = (arr) => {

        if (arr.length > 1) {
            console.log("inside func2 ", acc);
            let likeArr = singArr(arr, arr[0]);
            console.log(likeArr, "like");
            arr = deleteVal(arr, arr[0]);
            acc.push(likeArr);
            return recursive(mainArr);
        }
        else {
            return acc;
        }
    }
    
    return recursive(mainArr)
};
```

Also, I believe the code posted doesn't return the desired output. You can probably do the following:

```js
const array1 = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];
array1.sort((a,b) => a-b);

const map = new Map();

array1.forEach((item) => { 
    if(map.has(item)) {
        const storedItem = map.get(item);
        map.set(item, Array.isArray(storedItem) ? [...storedItem, item] : [storedItem, item])
    } else {
        map.set(item, item);
    }
});

console.log(Array.from(map.values()))
```

Comment: So much cleaner than the road I was going down! Still need to get used to al lot of the ES6 stuff...Map, Spread etc.

Answer (score 2):

inside your recursive function you are doing
return recursive(mainArr);
instead try to return recursive(arr);

Answer (score 1):

You never call the function `recursive`.

```
const sortArray = (mainArr) => {
    let acc = [];
    console.log(acc, "acc");
    const recursive = (arr) => {

        if (arr.length > 1) {
            console.log("inside func2 ", acc);
            let likeArr = singArr(arr, arr[0]);
            console.log(likeArr, "like");
            arr = deleteVal(arr, arr[0]);
            acc.push(likeArr);
            return recursive(mainArr);
        }
        else {
            return acc;
        }
    }
    
    recursive(mainArr) //<--- Call it!
};
```

You will also notice that `sortArray` does not return anything, so you may want to change `recursive(mainArr)` to `return recursive(mainArr)` to get a return.

Of note, the code does not produce the desired result, but this fix should get you going.

Comment: Just stuck in an endless loop but thanks for that!

Comment: @Toby yah I didn't solve the recursive solution for you, just the problem you were handling. Recursive functions tend to do that when they never hit their exit case.